# using different request parser depending on the queried route

Tags: http, c++11, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm Implementing a mini http server using boost beast. the server has two different routes POST **/upload/**...  and the other one is POST **/info**. The first one is used for uploading some big files and the other one is for hadling json objects. To keep the performance as hight as possible am I trying to parse each route with the suitable parser file_body and string_body/dynamic_body. 
I was hoping that it is possible to do something like:

```
http::async_read_header(
            socket_,
            buffer_,
            request_,
            [self](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t)
            {
                if (!ec)
                    self->request_.body().data();
            });
```

but it seems not possible.

Is there any way to use different request bodies depending on header info?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what is being asked. Specifically, what the relation between the types mentioned and the "problem code" is. Can you share a SSCCE/MVCE that demonstrates the problem (simplified)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be covered in the docs but here's how to do it: Use the type `beast::request_parser<beast::empty_body>` to first read the header, and then depending on the contents of the header you move-construct a new parser from the old one with the body type you want. Example:

```
// Deferred body type commitment
request_parser<empty_body> req0;
...
request_parser<string_body> req{std::move(req0)};
```

You can read the complete documentation on switching body types here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__parser/parser/overload5.html

Comment: the solution faills with an unexpected_body error: I use an empty_body in my read_async and upgrade it to a file_body depending on the header-infos but the async_read throw the execption

Comment: As both the question and the answer state, you "first read the header" using `async_read_header`.  Then use `async_read` after switching the body type.